# Generate a Hashcode for a string that is platform independent

Tags: c#, .net, hash, hashcode

We have an application that

- Generates a hash code on a string
- Saves that hash code into a DB along with associated data
- Later, it queries the DB using the string hash code for retrieving the data

This is obviously a bug because the value returned from string.GetHashCode() varies from .NET versions and architectures (32/64 bit). To complicate matters, we're too close to a release to refactor our application to stop serializing hash codes and just query on the strings instead. What we'd like to do is come up with a quick and dirty fix for now, and refactor the code later to do it the right way.

The quick and dirty fix seems like creating a static GetInvariantHashCode(string s) helper method that is consistent across architectures.

Can suggest an algorithm for generating a hashcode on a string that is equivalent on 32 bit and 64 bit architecture?

A few more notes:

- I'm aware that HashCodes are not unique. If a hashcode returns a match on two different strings, we post process the results to find the exact match. It is not used as a primary key.
- I believe the architect's intent was to speed up the searches by querying on a long instead of an NVarChar

Comment: As others have pointed what you want to do is simply not possible.  I do not see a way that will solve your problem and avoid collisions.

Comment: Well, if that's your intent, just let the database index the strings for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm aware that HashCodes are not unique. If a hashcode returns a match on two different strings, we post process the results to find the exact match. It is not used as a primary key.
>
> I believe the architect's intent was to speed up the searches by querying on a long instead of an NVarChar

**Then just let the database index the strings for you!**

Look, I have no idea how large your domain is, but you're going to get collisions very rapidly with very high likelihood if it's of any decent size at all. It's the birthday problem with a lot of people relative to the number of birthdays. You're going to have collisions, and lose any gain in speed you might think you're gaining by not just indexing the strings in the first place.

Anyway, you don't need us if you're stuck a few days away from release and you really need an invariant hash code across platform. There are really dumb, really fast implementations of hash code out there that you can use. Hell, you could come up with one yourself in the blink of an eye:

```
string s = "Hello, world!";
int hash = 17;
foreach(char c in s) {
    unchecked { hash = hash * 23 + c.GetHashCode(); } 
}
```

Or you could use the old Bernstein hash. And on and on. Are they going to give you the performance gain you're looking for? I don't know, they weren't meant to be used for this purpose. They were meant to be used for balancing hash tables. You're not balancing a hash table. You're using the wrong concept.

**Edit (the below was written before the question was edited with new salient information)**:

You can't do this, at all, theoretically, without some kind of restriction on your input space. Your problem is far more severe than `String.GetHashCode` differening from platform to platform.

There are a lot of instances of `string`. In fact, way more instances than there are instances of `Int32`. So, because of the piegonhole principle, you will have collisions. You can't avoid this: your `string`s are pigeons and your `Int32` hash codes are piegonholes and there are too many pigeons to go in the pigeonholes without some pigeonhole getting more than one pigeon. Because of collision problems, you can't use hash codes as unique keys for strings. It doesn't work. Period.

The only way you can make your current proposed design work (using `Int32` as an identifier for instances of `string`) is if you restrict your input space of strings to something that has at size less than or equal to the number of `Int32`s. Even then, you'll have difficulty coming up with an algorithm that maps your input space of `string`s to `Int32` in a unique way.

Even if you try to increase the number of pigeonholes by using SHA-512 or whatever, you still have the possibility of collisions. I doubt you considered that possibility previously in your design; this design path is DOA. And that's not what SHA-512 is for anyway, it's not to be used for unique identification of messages. It's just to reduce the likelihood of message forgery.

> To complicate matters, we're too close to a release to refactor our application to stop serializing hash codes and just query on the strings instead.

Well, then you have a tremendous amount of work ahead of you. I'm sorry you discovered this so late in the game.

I note the documentation for `String.GetHashCode`:

> The behavior of `GetHashCode` is dependent on its implementation, which might change from one version of the common language runtime to another. A reason why this might happen is to improve the performance of `GetHashCode`.

And from `Object.GetHashCode`:

> The GetHashCode method is suitable for use in hashing algorithms and data structures such as a hash table.

Hash codes are for balancing hash tables. They are not for identifying objects. You could have caught this sooner if you had used the concept for what it is meant to be used for.

Comment: Seriously, I have no idea what is going on in your shop that you are just now discovering this.

Comment: Someone tried to do something clever; as it frequently turns out, clever != correct. It is alarming that this got through design review, code review, and passed SQA. However, one (admittedly substantial) design flaw is not definitive evidence of an incompetent software team.

Comment: Sorry, I think it is a major failure.

Comment: Obviously, correctness is more important than performance. I think a custom hash or a Bernstein hash sounds like the quick and dirty fix to go with.

Comment: At least someone (Me) noticed the problem before a customer reported it. :-D

Answer (score 3):

You should just use SHA512.

Note that hashes are not (and cannot be) unique.
If you need it to be unique, just use the identity function as your hash.

Comment: You can even just use SHA256. You don't have to worry about hash codes not being unique. Even people who have tried their hardest to find a SHA256 collision have been unable to do so. You're more likely to get hit by lightning five times in the same month than to find a SHA256 collision by accident.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: You still don't want to rely on a demonstrably false assumption.  (even if you probably won't have more than 2^256 strings)

Comment: You would have to be a complete fool to be adding a fifteenth lock on your front door when the window is open. There are failure modes that are billions of times more likely than a SHA256 collision. You might as well argue that not making your roof asteroid proof is "relying on the false assumption" that your house won't get hit by an asteroid.

Comment: @David Schwartz: I think you're slightly misunderstanding what it means that people haven't found collisions. What that means is that if someone gives you a SHA-256 hash, can you find two strings `s` and `t` that both produce that hash and can you do it without using brute force? Right now, we can't. That, however, doesn't mean that collisions don't happen. Finding a collision is theoretically easy. Just make 2^256 + 1 strings and hash them all and then we have a collision somewhere in that pile of hashes.

Comment: @Jason: Although that is obviously true, _no-one_ deals with 2^256 different strings.  That's more than the number of atoms in the universe.  David may be right; in general use, you may not need to worry about collisions (I have no source for that belief, but it sounds correct).  However, I like my designs to be architecturaly sound.

Comment: @Jason You're essentially arguing against all of computer science. (For example, by your same argument, we can't use SSL, since an attacker can simply factor the public key.) An attack or vulnerability that is impractical by billions of orders of magnitude *should* be ignored. Otherwise all roofs would be asteroid proof, and that's an obviously absurd waste of resources.

Comment: @David Schwartz: No, I'm not. All I said is that your understanding of what it means that it's hard to find a collision is not entirely correct. I don't know what argument I gave that you think can be construed to saying we can't use SSL, but I certainly meant no such thing.

Comment: @Jason Any argument you make that we should do something about the possibility of SHA256 collisions will lead to the conclusion that we should never use SSL. Because the risk is precisely the same, and the only thing we can do about it (other than mentally acknowledging it) with SSL is not use SSL because it's fundamental.

Comment: @Jason Just look back at your comment. And re-read my last comment (before this one), particularly the first sentence. When a person is designing a roof why would you point out that it's not asteroid proof? Just for grins? The only possible point is that it should be, or the designer should consider that it's not. That's a nonsensical waste of time, since other failure modes are billions of orders of magnitude more likely.

Comment: @David Schwartz: My comment that says you slightly misunderstood what the problem of finding collisions is? How does that imply we shouldn't use SHA-256 or SSL? Come on. You misunderstood me. Point to something very specific so I can clear it up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7482/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-jason)

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the managed cryptography classes (such as [SHA512Managed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha512managed.aspx)) to compute a platform independent hash via [ComputeHash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a.aspx).  This will require converting the string to a byte array (ie: using [Encoding.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes.aspx) or some other method), and be slow, but be consistent.

That being said, a hash is not guaranteed unique, and is really not a proper mechanism for uniqueness in a database.  Using a hash to store data is likely to cause data to get lost, as the first hash collision will overwrite old data (or throw away new data).

Comment: ...unless the database design allows for hash collisions.  For example, the the column storing the hash value could have a non-unique index.

Comment: @phoog True - but that was why I suggested it's not a good way to check for "uniqueness in a database" ;)

Comment: Oops!  By reading too quickly, I somehow missed that part of the sentence. :-)